# Duplicated results returning in output of XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm getting really familiar with the paradigms and mechanics of XSLT these days and for that I have to thank this community. You have helped me see some of the fallacies in my past coding methods with XSLT (and coding all together!).

However, XPATH is still really really new to me. I find it varies from instantly being able to pull what I want out of a XML, to getting weird or no results.

Herein lies my current question today. I have the following snippet from my XML:

```
<Passenger>
    <PassengerName>
    <Title>MR</Title>
    <FirstName>MANLY</FirstName>
    <LastName>DUDE</LastName>
    </PassengerName>
</Passenger>
```

The above can repeat a number of times in the XML but I can assure you that it doesn't in this scenario.

I'm using the following XSLT, to call a template every time it comes across a new "Passenger" node.

```
<!-- List through each Passenger for their Name details here -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="//Passenger" mode="text"/>
```

And here is the template as a whole that is called:

```
<xsl:template match="Passenger" mode="text">
    <xsl:value-of select="PassengerName/Title"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="PassengerName/FirstName"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="PassengerName/LastName"/>
</xsl:template>
```

However this outputs:

```
MR MANLY DUDE
MR MANLY DUDE
```

I have tried a number of different XPATH configurations between the `value-of`'s and the `apply-templates match=` and for the life of me I can not get just one to come back.

To my understanding `"//Passenger"` will target ANY `<Passenger>` node, and only the node that follows that exact name. I have been over my XML, more times than I would care to admit and there is definitely not a second copy of this in it.

The template that also controls the template that contains my `apply-templates` is also not being called twice and is inside a `<xsl:template match="/">`.

Any help or explanation on why this isn't coinciding with what I expected to happen?

Thanks in advance as always,
Alex.

EDIT: Strangely, when I add another  snippet, it goes to 3 `MR MANLY DUDE`. Does this indicate it is actually picking something up in the XML somehow?

Comment: Please provide an [**Minimal, *Complete*, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that exhibits the problem.  Thanks.

Comment: My guess which is a pure guess since you need to show us more ... You are hitting it in a mode of text and the again maybe in a generic match. If you use a good debugging tool like oXygen, you can easily find these things.

Comment: Modify the content of your template match = passenger, mode text. If in your result your 2 lines are modified, then the template is called twice (1) or you have 2 occurences of data (2). Modify then the data, to see if both of your lines are modified (then it s 1, or not then it s 2)

Comment: btw, why are you doing an apply template of //Passenger instead of Passenger inside its possible ancestors